# Parabens vs. parabéns

Tags: etymology, orthography

Is there an etymological link between the word parabens in English (ex. Soap without parabens) and parabéns (congratulations) in Portuguese?

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because it's explicitly about the etymology of the two words.

Answer (score 8):

No, English paraben is from *para*-hydroxy*ben*zoic acid, and Portuguese parabéns is from para + bem.

For chemical compounds, *para* comes from Greek παρά (pará) 'besides', and *benzoic* has its root in Arabic. See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/benzoin).

The two components of the Portuguese words are both from Latin. Here, *para* is from Latin *per* + *ad*. *Per* is not related to Greek παρά (pará), but to Greek περί (perí).